# How to call category method in another class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have category class have method to encode the url. So how to use this method in another class. Thank in advance

NSString+EncodeURL.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (EncodeURL)
-(NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;
@end
```

NSString+EncodeURL.m

```
-(NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding {
    return (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                               (CFStringRef)self,
                                                               NULL,
                                                               (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",                                                               CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding)));
}
```

and in another class. How to convert urlString to a string using urlEncodeUsingEncoding in Category class

```
#import "WatchVideosViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"
#import "ImageRequest.h"
#import "Constant.h"
#import "ImageCache.h"
#import "NSString+EncodeURL.h"
@interface WatchVideosViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageBackground;

@end

@implementation WatchVideosViewController

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString * CellIndentifier = kCellName;
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIndentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *dictVideo = [self.videoList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //start indicator
    [cell.indicator startAnimating];
    //set title
    NSString *titleVideo = [dictVideo objectForKey:kTitleKey];
    [cell.myLabel setText:titleVideo];
    // set image url
    NSString *urlVideo = [dictVideo objectForKey:kUrlKey];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlVideo];
    NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
    NSString *encodeURL=[urlString ]
//encode url
```

Comment: You call it like any other method. Of course you need to import the .h file too.

Comment: i do it but it not working

Comment: Why don't you update your question to include the code where you actually try to use the category method.

Comment: i updated the question. please check for me tks

Comment: Just post the relevant code, not your whole project.

Comment: i cant call encodeURL method in category class in urlString to convert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example with `NSStringEncoding` is `NSUTF8StringEncoding`. You can convert urlString to encodeURL by call:

```
NSString *encodeURL=[urlString urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

function `CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding()` will convert `NSUTF8StringEncoding` to `kCFStringEncodingUTF8`

Comment: i try but NSString not have urlEncodeUsingEncoding . It only have EncodeWithCoder method

Comment: use NSUTF8StringEncoding for encode URL. just call NSString *encodeURL=[urlString urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: as I edited my answer, if U want to convert string to encoded URL string, try it

Answer (score 4):

In the file you want to make use of `-urlEncodeUsingEncoding:`, simply add:

```
#import "NSString+EncodeURL.h"
```

All `NSString` instances in that file will respond to `-urlEncodeUsingEncoding:`.

Answer (score 1):

## import "NSString+EncodeURL.h"

in the class u want to run NSString+EncodeURL.h--this class's method

Now u got to select where u got to run the method of (NSString+EncodeURL.h) this class.

suppose u want it to run in viewDidLoad,so
Create an instance of the class in the method.

NSString+EncodeURL *myInstance;
[myInstance methodname];

Answer (score 1):

In the class where you want to use the category method, just simply import the category header as below.

```
#import "NSString+EncodeURL.h"
```

Then, use the category method as below

```
NSString *encodeURL = [urlString urlEncodeUsingEncoding:urlString];
```

Thats it, Simple, Bingo!

Answer (score 0):

As in your code if you want to encode the url just write

```
NSString *encodeURL=[urlString urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; //whataver encoding you want just pass
```

If code completion is not showing than there may be problem with indexing just terminae xcode reopen clean and build.It should work.